# Is there a way to hide the C++ class definition across compilation unit?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there anyway to hide the C++ class definition across compilation units?

Consider,

```
//test1.cpp
struct local
{
    local()
    {
       std::cout<<"test1::local\n";
    }
};
void test1()
{
    local l;
}


//test2.cpp
struct local
{
    local()
    {
        std::cout<<"test2::local\n";
    }
};

void test2()
{
    local l;
}



//main.cpp
void test1();
void test2();
int main()
{
   test1();
   test2();
}
```

it should link & print like below,

```
test1::local
test2::local
```

I need a mechanism similar like static functions, i don't want use namespace or anonymous namespace because still its symbol information exported in the object file.

Comment: Sure: give your classes different names. The code here violates the one-definition rule (ODR), because it defines the **same** name in two different ways. This produces undefined behavior.

Comment: Anonymous namespaces are *exactly* what you need and symbol information is an implementation detail that you should not have to worry about.

Answer (score 7):

You can use an anonymous namespace:

```
namespace {
    struct local
    {
        local()
        {
           std::cout<<"test1::local\n";
        }
    };
}

void test1()
{
    local l;
}
```

That effectively restricts the scope of the name `local` to the translation unit where it's used. (Formally that's not correct, but if you think of it that way you won't go wrong)

Comment: @chris - whoops, I didn't notice that (bogus) requirement.

Comment: Aha, I almost couldn't remember any of the name to find it, but http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/02/06/10391383.aspx

Comment: Pedant note: they are called unnamed, not anonymous.

Comment: @CoryNelson - so why have I always called them anonymous namespaces? Never mind...

Comment: What do you mean by "Formally that's not correct"? (Just curious here.)

Comment: @kbok - with `static int i;` the name `i` has internal linkage, so is not visible outside the translation unit where it's defined. With an unnamed namespace the name has external linkage, so technically it's visible, but it gets munged by the compiler so that it's unrecognizable. That's because of the pre-C++11 rule that only names with external linkage could be used as template arguments. Giving names in the unnamed namespace internal linkage would have made more sense, but it would also have meant that they couldn't be used as template arguments. C++11 changed both of those rules (continued)

Comment: (continuation) so that template arguments can have internal linkage and names defined in the unnamed namespace have internal linkage. I haven't internalized C++11, so I was referring to the old rules.

Comment: @PeteBecker You are correct, I need some way to define a class with internal linkage. Is it possible? Anything added to C++11 related to this?

Comment: @Arun Why exported symbol name bothers you? If you're interfacing with another language, there is no way you can use this information anyway, and it also won't clash with the other language identifiers as C++ name mangling is not standarized. Two classes with the same name in two files, but in anonymous namespace are two different classes, so what's the problem?

Comment: @PeteBecker I just want to reduce the unnecessary linkage overhead. If the class definition is localized(non public classes, may be private classes) then linker no need to process their symbols. Will get a fast linking for larger c++ code bases.

Answer (score 0):

Your code violates the one definition rule here, because you have two classes with the same scope and name but different definitions. Therefore all bets are off and `it should link & print like below,` is a completely false statement because your code has undefined behavior.

However in this case I think a function-local type may be exactly what you want, for example:

```
//test1.cpp
void test1()
{
    struct local
    {
        local()
        {
           std::cout<<"test1::local\n";
        }
    };

    local l;
}
```

But keep in mind that the normal solution is to use anonymous namespaces to separate such things, and just strip the binary if you're worried about extra symbols.